# How do I use Mathematica computation of special functions in Microsoft Excel computation?

Tags: special-functions, data, excel, excellink

I have a model equation which I find somehow easier to compute with some experimental data in Microsoft Excel. I had an initial model which is basically a Bessel function. In Mathematica, I was able to compute the model equation with this code:

```
With[{s = {i, 0, 15, 0.5}}, Table[{i^2, i^3, BesselJ[i, 5.2]}, s]]
```

I was as well able to compute the model for experimental data without smooth ranges. The current model is essentially a Legendre equation which I could not find in the Excel formula bar. The challenge I have with the current model is that I have experimental data (of 300 rows) which do not have smooth ranges and I need to use them to determine the model function using Legendre function (a special function). Hence, is it possible to use the incredible computational power of Wolfram Mathematica within the formula bar of Excel or vice versa? 
Your kind suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You work with experimental data in Excel and you do not find that dangerous or cumbersome? Why not write a concise _Mathematica_ notebook that imports the Excel data and performs all computations in a reproducible way? Then store the notebook along with the data for later reference and possible correction.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I perfectly agree with you. Unfortunately, my boss is old school and Excel-compliant. The model must be explained in the way that he understands most.

Comment: Still the computations can be done in Mathematica, no? You can also `Export` to `XLS`, `XLSX`, and their ilk...

Comment: Alright. I will try that!

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher, many thanks!

Comment: So it worked out for you? In that case, I am glad to be of help!

Comment: Yes, thank you for your kind advise. I have been able to get a way around the problem.